# Using OpenStreetMap in Bing Maps WPF Controlv 1.0

Tags: wpf, dictionary, bing, openstreetmap

I recently read this [article](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/11/12/Display_OpenStreetMap_Imagery_using_Bing_Maps_Silverlight_Control_Version_1_RTW.aspx). Which uses the Silverlight Bing maps control to display map data from OpenStreetMap.
But I'm going to use OpenStreatMap in WPF and use Bing Maps WPF Control v1.0

My question is how can I do this in WPF.
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using this code of a WPF Map Control that uses openstreetmap Data?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87944/WPF-Map-Control-using-openstreetmap-org-Data